# Breadcrumbs aren't working at all

Tags: panels, breadcrumbs, theming

I'm trying to get my breadcrumbs to display in a default site template with panels, but they aren't showing up when I go to view my pages, although everything else is. It also says that they are there in layout designer.  I downloaded custom_breadcrumb module in hopes that it might right something with panels, but no luck.

This is how I'm adding them to my panels;
Add Content > Page Elements > Breadcrumb > save & update

No other settings.  It may also be worth mentioning that I'm using Bear and Aurora base  theme.

What can I do to get these back up?

Comment: Are you using the Bear Skin theme? Does the page.tpl.php have `<?php print $breadcrumb; ?>` in it?

Comment: Nope, I'm actually using Aurora to theme with and panels everywhere for most of my templating, I probably should have mentioned that earlier.

I tried adding the <?php print $breadcrumb; ?> to page.tpl.php but that didn't do anything unfortunately. I'm not sure that it would either because panels everywhere is probably overriding it, right?

Comment: did you clear your cache?

Comment: Yup, ran Cron also.

Comment: Have you tried looking at hook_breadcrumb to see what your getting in the $variables argument???

Comment: Not yet, I'm not sure how I would go about it.  Is there a command in drush that I can use to do this, or do I just print it somehow in one of my templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is related to using blockify, which is a requirement for Aurora. It is fixable with a patch.

There is a full explanation along with the patch here:  https://drupal.org/node/2074249

If you're new to drupal like me and haven't installed a patch before here is a guide with links to a video that explains how to go about doing this:  https://drupal.org/patch/apply